# How to get a mansory/pinterest layout with flexbox and flex-direction:row (not column)

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Please see this:

[image]

Basically these are the conditions:

- I need the description box to be just below the title (so moved up, not alingned with the features box)
- I MUST use row, not column flex-direction (and I know this IS the problem)
- I'd like to use flexbox only because of its order property. In fact, I would only need to use the order property on breakpoints. Otherwise I could avoid using flexbox at all in this case.

I don't know if there's a way to do what I need, since it's not flexbox nature at all. But maybe some trick exists?

Comment: Nope...there isn't. That's why Masonry exists still. However, without seeing the structure it's hard to comment further. Nested flexbox might do something...but generally...NO.

Comment: I suspected. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just 4 divs in a container. If you can break it up into two column divs (without using flex-columns) this is pretty simple...depending on what you're actually going for.